# Haisu: Pink Rose

Tags: mazes, grid-deduction

HAISU is a portmanteau of three Japanese words - 'hairu', to enter, 'su', number, and 'hausu', an English borrow word meaning house, of course.
Together, we get a meaning of 'enter number house', which I have roughly translated to English as 'Room Count'.

The rules are simple - draw a path from the O to the X, passing through every cell in the grid exactly once. The grid is divided into several rooms. When your path passes over a cell with the big number N, it must be the Nth time you have entered the room. If a room has a small number m in the top left corner, you must enter that room a total of m times. An example Haisu puzzle and its unique solution are shown below.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this example puzzle clarifies the rules. Your actual challenge is this!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer

Only good way to enter 5 times I could find. Also must hit the 1 on first entrance.

> [image]

Logical prolongation of lines that shouldn't touch each others.

> [image]

The path coming from the entrance will be forced to take this path eventually.

> [image]

Only way to hit the 3 on the 3rd entrance and respect the current flow of the lines.

> [image]

Further deductions based on straight forward paths.

> [image]

Some of my logical deductions were not so logical after all. Here is the result after some minor revisions.

> [image]

Comment: Nice! There is a purely logical solve path to the finish (which, interestingly, does things almost in reverse order to what you've done!), but you do present the correct answer :)

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper, could you explain how this answer works? It seems to me that this path enters the small-2 room 3 times.

Comment: @Passage oops, I hadn't noticed that. The intended answer doesn't do that. The general topology of stack readers solution matched mine so I didn't look closely enough at the details. This is not the correct answer.

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper My bad, just fixed it... I think.

Comment: @passage Stackreader has just corrected his answer to the correct one. This solution no longer has a logical pathway leading to the answer, but I'll leave it green ticked anyway.